# How do I paused an audio whenever user skips the audio scrubber?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pause an audio whenever the user manipulates the skips/retract the audio scrubber. The following code does not work properly.

This is what I tried so far.

```js
const pupHymn = document.querySelector(".pup-hymn");
pupHymn.addEventListener('seeked', () => {
     pupHymn.pause();
};
pupHymn.addEventListener('seeking', () => {
     pupHymn.pause();
};
```

Comment: "*does not work properly*" how does it work? What's the error? And is the missing `)` closing parenthesis also in your real code or is it a syntax error only in this post?

Comment: My bad, the missing parenthesis is just a syntax error in the post. The problem is when I try to adjust the current time via the audio scrubber, sometimes it successfully gets paused and sometimes it does not.